# Combining Set of Text field from multiple field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Code. This is my text field. it can be more than 1 sets. In the example i have 3 sets.

```
<DIV class="product-item float-clear">
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]"/></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="webcampics" /></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><select id="status"  class="webcampics" >
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
<option value="M">Maybe</option>
</select></DIV>
</DIV>
```

Here is my Jquery.

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('webcampics'),
                names = [].map.call(inputs, function (input) {
            return input.value;
        }).join('|');
```

The output is:

> a@mail.com|Y|b@mail.com|Y|c@mail.com|Y

Expected Output is:

> a@mail.com|Y;b@mail.com|Y;c@mail.com|Y

Answer (score 1):

Use `nodeName` to check the input where you want to add new character and do string concatenation.

```
names = [].map.call(inputs, function (input) {
     var tempStr =  input.value;
     if(input.nodeName == "SELECT")
     {
         tempStr += ";";
     }
     return tempStr;
}).join('|');
```

FYI, you can also use `each()` to achieve the same.

```js
$('button').click(function(){

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('webcampics'),
    
names = [].map.call(inputs, function (input) {
            var tempStr =  input.value;
            if(input.nodeName == "SELECT")
            {
              tempStr += ";";
            }
            else
            {
              tempStr += "|";  
            }
            return tempStr;
        }).join("");
console.log(names);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV class="product-item float-clear">
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]"/></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="webcampics" /></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><select id="status"  class="webcampics" >
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
<option value="M">Maybe</option>
</select></DIV>

  <DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]"/></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="webcampics" /></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><select id="status"  class="webcampics" >
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
<option value="M">Maybe</option>
</select></DIV>
  
</DIV>
<button>GET OUTPUT</button>
```

Comment: its working! thanks. Can I ask for details on explanation on the code of how it work? like the keyword of "SELECT".

Comment: Just console the node name you will understand it gives you the input tag

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you the desire output. You can use node name property of input element to achieve this.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var names ="";
$('.button').bind('click', function(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('webcampics'),
names = [].map.call(inputs, function (input) {
     var values =  input.value;
     if(input.nodeName == "SELECT")
     {
         values += ";";
     }
     return values;
}).join('|');
console.log(names);

})

})
```

HTML:

```
<body>

    <DIV class="product-item float-clear">
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]"/></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="webcampics" /></DIV>
<DIV class="float-left"><select id="status"  class="webcampics" >
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
<option value="M">Maybe</option>
</select></DIV>
</DIV>

<input type="button" class="button" value="submit">
</body>
```